# Symfony 1.4 - route by query string parameters

Tags: php, routes, symfony-1.4

Is it possible to route request to controllers/actions by query string parameters?
And how to do it using routing.yml file?

I mean:

```
/some/path?do=action1... 


some_route:
    url: /some/path
    param: { module: module1, action: action1 }
    requirements:
        do: action1       <--- ???


/some/path?do=action2

some_route2
   url: /some/path
   param: { module: module1, action: action2 }
   requirements:
        do: action2       <--- ???
```

or some common route:

```
some_route:
    url: /some/path?do=:action
    param: { module: module1, action: action }
    requirements:
        do: action\d+
```

Thanks!

Comment: You want different actions for different routes, isn't it? Don't understand your problem.

Comment: Yes, different actions for different 'do' values...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do so by creating generic rule in `routing.yml`:

```
generic_rule:
    url: /some/path/:action
    param: {module: yourmodule}
```

In this case when you call `/some/path/index` then `indexAction` method of `yourmodule` will be called.

You can even create more generic rule, where both `action` and `module` are variables:

```
more_generic_rule:
    url: /some/path/:module/:action
```

Check [doc](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/09-Links-and-the-Routing-System#chapter_09_routing_configuration) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can make one action which will check the `do` parameter and forward you to the proper action, e.g.

```
main_action:
    url: /some/path/:do
    param: { module: yourmodule, action: mainAction }
    requirements: 
      do: action\d+
```

Then in the `yourmodule/actions/actions.class.php`:

```
public function executeMainAction(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $do = $request->getParameter('do');

    if (doParameterIsOk($do)) { 
        $this->forward('yourmodule', $do);
    } else {
        // Handle bad `do` parameter.
    }
}
```

Comment: I get 'do' param in query string and requirements: do: <something> does not work. if it was working it was solve my problem :)
But it looks like realistic solution even if it force me to deal with routing in the actions.

Comment: The requirements set in the yml file do not work on query params. You have to handle the validation by yourself in action.